# How to show error message using react-hook-form in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

How to add validation, I want show error message on for phone number field   (helperText, min 10 , max 10 ) and also show error message if submitted without 10  numeric digit

```
import ReactPhoneInput from "react-phone-input-2"
import {TextField,Button}from "@material-ui/core"

const {register, handleSubmit,formState: { errors }} = useForm()

const getData= (data) => {
   console.log(data.username)
   console.log(data.phone);
}
```

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(getData)} >

  <Controller
        control={control}
        name="phone"
        render={({ field: { ref, ...field } }) => (
          <ReactPhoneInput {...field}
            inputExtraProps={{ref, required: true, autoFocus: true }}
            country={"in"}
            onlyCountries={["in"]}
            countryCodeEditable={false}
            specialLabel={"Player Mobile Number"}
          />
        )}
      />
<Button type='submit>Submit</Button> 
</form>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the `rules` prop of the `<Controller />` component to define your validation rules. Check the rules section [here](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register) for more info.

To display the errors you have to use `formState` object returned by `useForm`.

```
export default function App() {
  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  const isNumber = (number) => !isNaN(number) || "Must be a number";

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name="phone"
        rules={{
          required: { value: true, message: "Required" },
          minLength: { value: 12, message: "Min Length" },
          maxLength: { value: 12, message: "Max Length" },
          validate: isNumber
        }}
        render={({ field: { ref, ...field } }) => (
          <ReactPhoneInput
            {...field}
            inputExtraProps={{
              ref,
              required: true,
              autoFocus: true
            }}
            country={"in"}
            onlyCountries={["in"]}
            countryCodeEditable={false}
            specialLabel={"Player Mobile Number"}
          />
        )}
      />
      {errors.phone && <p>{errors.phone.message}</p>}
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit React Hook Form - react-phone-input-2 (forked)]